# Get weighted rating based on votes

Tags: mysql

I have a table named "visits" that contains the cols: "rid" (room id), "rating".

**table: visits**

```
-----------------
| rid  | rating |
-----------------
|   5  |   8    |
|   5  |   6    |
|   8  |   9    |
|   5  |   7    |
|   5  |   0    |
|   4  |   5    |
-----------------
```

as shown above, every visit has an option to be rated from 0 to 10.

I don't want votes of 0 to be counted as votes.

Now I've been using this query to get the best rated rooms (but with weight! So that 1 vote of 10 won't be better than 40 votes of 9).

For example, output:

```
-----------------
| rid  | rating |
-----------------
|   5  |  7.42  |
|   8  |  6.94  |
|   4  |  6.43  |
-----------------
```

Query:

```
select t1.rid, 

((t1.avg_num_votes*t1.avg_rating)+(t1.this_num_votes*t1.this_rating))/(t1.avg_num_votes+t1.this_num_votes) as rating

from (

SELECT

    rid,

    (SELECT count(rid) FROM visits) / (SELECT count(DISTINCT rid) FROM visits) AS avg_num_votes,

    (SELECT avg(rating) FROM visits) AS avg_rating,

    count(rid) as this_num_votes,

    avg(rating) as this_rating

FROM

    visits

    where rating>0

GROUP BY 

    rid

    ) as t1

    Order by rating desc
```

I feel like the output isn't very accurate.

Do you see any problem in the code? Thanks.

Comment: Please include sample data, table definitions and expected output in your question

Comment: Hi, added more information.

Comment: @D.Yeffet When you have (only) the rating `5` for the room id `4` in your example input, how do you get the rating `6.43` for the same room in your example output? What is the calculation behind this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess by weighted average you would need something like

```
SELECT rid ,
COUNT(*) room_votes,
SUM(v.rating) room_rating,
(SUM(v.rating)/(t.total_votes * 10)) weighted_rating,
t.total_votes 
FROM visits v
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 
        COUNT(*) total_votes 
        FROM visits 
        WHERE rating <> 0
) t
WHERE v.rating <> 0
GROUP BY v.rid
```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/VZYNM51178)

> weighted_rating = sum of rating per room / count of all votes for all rooms from table and * 10 (due to rating range 1 - 10)

### Sample output

```
================================================================
   rid  room_votes  room_rating  weighted_rating  total_votes  
------  ----------  -----------  ---------------  -------------
     4           1            5           0.1000              5
     5           3           21           0.4200              5
     8           1            9           0.1800              5
================================================================
```

Comment: Thanks, but rating should be something like 8.52 for example, no 0...

Comment: @D.Yeffet Can you elaborate it more how rating should be 8.52 or what is the logic you have for weighted rating ?

Comment: You don't understand me. Weighted rating goes 0,1, 0.42, 0.18 etc (for your example), but how does it make sense when ratings are from 1 to 10?

Comment: @D.Yeffet Have you seen the [second result set](http://rextester.com/VZYNM51178) in provided demo link, for decimals i have added * 10 remove this part you will get the ratings in decimals > 0

Comment: Hi sir, I have seen but all gives the same value: 7.5543 (for over 300 rooms)

Comment: @D.Yeffet Can you ask a new with all the details related to weighted rating calculation also include sample data, table definitions and expected output in your new question